# Set folder permission with Powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions

[Example of the goal, the crossout is the same user.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFO9q.png)

I've created a script that creates a folder based on users SAMaccount and it works like it should, it also gives full control on the folder, not inherited.

My goal is to set another set of full control permissions for the same user, but inherited from the "top folder" and the full control should should only applie to "this folder only"

My script so far is below:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Test,OU=Users,OU=Bla Groups,DC=Bla,DC=local" | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty sAMAccountName
ForEach($user in $users)
{
$newPath = Join-Path "c:\Temp\Test" -childpath $user
New-Item $newPath -type directory -Force

$acl = (Get-Item $newpath).GetAccessControl('Access')
$permission = "Bla.local\$user","FullControl",@("ContainerInherit","ObjectInherit"),"None","Allow"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl $newpath
}
```

Comment: If you want to _inherit_ an access control entry from the parent directory, you'll have to modify the ACL _on the parent directory_

Comment: I'd always the [NTFSSecurity](https://github.com/raandree/NTFSSecurity) module (example uses in link) when setting file permissions... it's much easier to use than `Set-Acl` as the commands emulate the way the GUI works.